# AWS GovCloud - Is there any way to identify whether a given AWS account ID is GovCloud or not?

Tags: amazon-web-services

For a given AWS account ID I need to check whether it is an AWS GovCloud account or not. Is there any API available to check that? Will be having the access key ID and secret access key

Comment: Do you mean you have credentials to the standard aws account or the govcloud aws account? Maybe `aws ec2 describe-regions --all-regions`, maybe `aws sts get-caller-identity` can help you.

Comment: Have credentials to govcloud. Here is the real time scenario - user will input account ID and access key IDs, but will not specify whether the give account is govcloud account or std account. So will be in a situation to check whether the given account ID is of govcloud or std account and then internally decide which end point has to be used ( as std and goovcloud will be having diff endpoints). So looking for possibility to see whether the given account ID is of govcloud or std account

Comment: In that case the two given solutions should work - but do you think it is a remotely good idea to let users input credentials into your application?